# Static property not instantiated in class from binding

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin, objective-sharpie

When I access static property `SharedController`, the value is null, but the API Definition generated by Objective Sharpie only provides a getter.

`BBDeviceController` is instantiated, but the `SharedController` property on it is null. Because it only has a getter, I do not believe I am able to instantiate the property in code. From what I can tell, `SharedController` is not being initialized in `BBDeviceController`'s constructor. I am unsure if `BBDeviceController` is a static class or just follows the singleton design pattern, but either way, newing up that class is not the solution.

BBDeviceController.h

```
@interface BBDeviceController : NSObject {
    NSObject <BBDeviceControllerDelegate>* delegate;

    BOOL debugLogEnabled;
    BOOL detectAudioDevicePlugged;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject <BBDeviceControllerDelegate>* delegate;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isDebugLogEnabled, setter=setDebugLogEnabled:) BOOL debugLogEnabled;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isDetectAudioDevicePlugged, setter=setDetectAudioDevicePlugged:) BOOL detectAudioDevicePlugged;

+ (BBDeviceController *)sharedController;
```

Resulting API Definition (`APIDefinition.cs`)

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[Protocol]
interface BBDeviceController
{
    ...
    // +(BBDeviceController *)sharedController;
    [Static]
    [Export("sharedController")]
    BBDeviceController SharedController { get; }
    ...
}
```

Call from project's view controller

```
public BBDeviceController bbDeviceController;
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    bbDeviceController = BBDeviceController.SharedController;
    ConnectDevice();
}

private void ConnectDevice()
{
    bbDeviceController.StartBTScan(new string[] { DEVICE_NAME }, 60);
}
```

From the documentation for the objective C library, you use `sharedController` like this:

`[[BBDeviceController sharedController] setDelegate:self];`

When trying to do the C# equivalent, I get an error because `SharedController` is null.
Something else that may be of interest is that the `SharedController` definition in the resulting API Definitions file was flagged with `[Verify(MethodToProperty)]`, and I manually had to add `[Static]` in order to access it from code.

Comment: `+ (BBDeviceController *)sharedController;` This is a class method, can not get a instance from it.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT How do I solve this? Do I change something in APIDefinition.cs, or is it an issue with the original library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exact issue is (it could be it's not linking correctly, it could be the plist settings aren't right, etc) but I have successfully done this with the latest SDK (v3.7.2 as of writing). Here are the steps:

#### 1. Use the following `sharpie` command to make the bindings:

`sharpie bind --output=. --namespace=WisePad2Binding --sdk=iphoneos13.2 --scope=<path-to-sdk>/BBDevice-iOS-SDK-3.7.2/Library <path-to-sdk>/BBDevice-iOS-SDK-3.7.2/Library/BBDeviceController.h`

#### 2. Remove the `[Verify]` tags

I went ahead and changed back all the methods changed to properties that were marked by `[Verify]` just to leave less up to chance.

#### 3. Add the libraries to your binding project

In the binding product, I didn't use the "Native References" folder (well, I tried initially and it did not work). Apparently the "old" way of making a binding project was to just drag the library onto the project root. When you do this, each library gets a `.linkwith.cs` attached to it (more on that in a sec). The libraries I added were:

- libBBDevice-iOS-AudioAndBT-3.7.2.a
- libBBDevice-iOS-AudioAndBT-3.7.2-simulator.a
- libBBDeviceOTA-iOS-1.5.4.a
- libBBDeviceOTA-iOS-1.5.4-simulator.a

Then in each `.linkwith.cs` file change the assembly attribute to be...

`[assembly: LinkWith ("<library-name>.a", SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "AudioToolbox AVFoundation CoreAudio CoreBluetooth CoreGraphics CoreFoundation CoreLocation ExternalAccessory Foundation MediaPlayer MessageUI QuartzCore SystemConfiguration UIKit", LinkerFlags = "-lc++ -lz -ObjC")]`

#### 4. Update your plist

Make sure you have all the stuff they list [here](https://developer.bbpos.com/docs/sdk/bbdevice/integration-guide/getting-started/ios-macos/) added to your plist or stuff will not work right.

#### 5. Tips

I couldn't get things to work correctly if I didn't do some (all?) things on the main thread, so I just perform all actions on the main thread. Also, don't set the delegate on the shared controller without calling `BBDeviceController.SharedController.ReleaseBBDeviceController()` (if you had a delegate previously set on there). My thoughts and prayers go out to anybody else trying to use this SDK with Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

When I do something like this, it's for a singleton class.
https://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

so your sharedController method, should either allocate your BBDeviceController or get it somewhere. Also, if you can share the library link so we are on the same page.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to be authenticated to view the documentation. It's for [BBPOS](https://developer.bbpos.com), but you have to have an account to view anything.